# Replacing the element with next largest element in array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to write a function for replacing an element the next largest element in an array if
`[12,32,10,8,89,48,21,56,9]` is given I want to make it like this `[89,89,89,89,89,56,56,56,9]`. In the given array since there is no element after 9 it will remain same

This is how far I got

```
def ele(arr, start, end):
    h = max(arr[start:end])
    hi = arr.index(h)

    if hi < len(arr):
        for i in range(start, hi):
            if i != arr[-1]:
                arr[i] = h
            else:
                arr[i] == arr[i]
    ele(arr, hi + 1, end)
  
         
          
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [123,5,2,78,2,1,789,21,72,17,56,555]
    end = len(arr)
    print(end)
    ele(arr, 0, end)
    print(arr)
```

This code is working only if the last element is not the highest. Can you help me doing this work

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want all values before the `max` value to be changed to the max and then all values after to be the second highest value?

Comment: It looks like a reversed rolling max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original code error occurs, when you give an empty sequence to `max()` function. To not do it add this to the beginning of `ele()` function

```
if start >= end:
    return
```

Also you can solve this problem easier. Walk through the array in reverse order. If the element is smaller than the next one, then it must be replaced with it, otherwise we have met a new maximum, now we replace with it.

```
arr = [12, 32, 10, 8, 89, 48, 21, 56, 9]

for i in range(len(arr)-2, -1, -1):
    if arr[i] < arr[i + 1]:
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 56, 56, 56, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind this solution is that its easier to iterate in ascending fashion

```py
lst = [12,32,10,8,89,48,21,56,9]

y=min(lst)-1
print(list(reversed([(y:=i) if i > y else y for i in reversed(lst)])))
```

```py
[89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 56, 56, 56, 9]
```

Heres whats going on in the main list comprehension:

```py
[(y:=i) if i > y else y for i in reversed(lst)]
```

a reversed version of the list is iterated through storing and appending the each element if its greater than `y` (the first element will always be greater than y in every scenario). If it is not greater than y, y will be appended until a greater element is found. then the list is reversed yet again to put it in its "original order"!

Comment: You can also always just go with `y = float('-inf')` for the initial value of `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question should be -  **Replace an element with the largest value of all to the right of it.**

You can do that easily like this:

- Initialize a variable `maxm` with the least value possible. *I am using `float('-inf')`*

> *`maxm` will store the `max` value of all the right side items of the current item in list.*

- Iterate over the list in reverse and keep updating the `maxm` using `max()`.
- Update the value of `lst` with this `maxm` value.

```
lst = [12,32,10,8,89,48,21,56,9]
maxm = float('-inf')

for i in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1):
    maxm = max(lst[i], maxm)
    lst[i] = maxm

print(lst)
```

```
[89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 56, 56, 56, 9]
```

**Time Comlexity: O(N)**

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate

arr=[123,5,2,78,2,1,789,21,72,17,56,555]
new_arr = list(accumulate(reversed(arr), max))[::-1]
print(new_arr)
```

Accumulate is like `functools.reduce` except it returns all intermediate values as well.  In this case what you want is a reverse-rolling max so we have to do a couple of reversals.